# How to get attribute from XML node?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to get the attribute URL from the media:thumbnail node.
This is my XML-code.

```
<item>
      <title>A nice title</title>
      <link>http://www.example.com</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 14 May 2014 12:45:12 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">art_art-s2/2119</guid>
      <media:thumbnail url="http://example.com/d7f4c6ebeed30107f56eff68cd431559a.jpg" height="716" width="607"/>
      <description>A short description</description>
    </item>
```

I can get the title like this but I do not know how to get the url for the thumbnail:

```js
doc.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as doing this:

```js
doc.item(i).getElementsByTagName("media:thumbnail").item(0).getAttribute("url")
```